# Kotlin Inheritance - Extend JVM class and interface which have same method names

Tags: kotlin, graphql, graphql-java

I have a custom `Exception` class which looks like this:

```
class GenericException(message: String?, errorCode: Int) : RuntimeException(message), GraphQLError {
.....
}
```

As you all know, `RuntimeException extends Throwable` which has a method called `getMessage()`

Now the issue is, this interface `GraphQLError` (which is a library interface) *also* has a method called `getMessage()`

As a result, compiler is complaining with this:

[image: constructor compiler error]

OK so I implement the method:

```
override fun getMessage(): String {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

Now I get this:

[image: Override Error]

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: I don't think that error is because you are implementing multiple classes/interface. It is completely possible in kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-rules but it is because of the Throwable class check if the error persists if you remove the implementation of your kotlin interface.

Answer (score 1):

What I guessed in the comments was right, kotlin allows multiple inheritence. It was indeed because of the Throwable class.

You can use `@JvmField` annotation to instruct the compiler not to generate getters and setters for the field and then create the getter/setter yourself.

```kotlin
interface HasMessage {
    fun getMessage(): String
}

class GenericException(
    @JvmField override val message: String?,  // var is also possible
    val errorCode: Int                        // I made it a property, might not be as well
) : RuntimeException(message), HasMessage {
    override fun getMessage(): String {
        // return of the super's getter, probably no use because you have field as property in this class
        val superGetMessage = super<RuntimeException>.message
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

[Play with the code yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/7i0C-D2V5).

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked! Learnt a new concept today.

Comment: Can you add a comment mentioning this work around to this [Kotlin issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653)?

Comment: Now it is not supporting in 1.6

Comment: Yeah I am back here to this question again after upgrading to kotlin 1.6.20